# Merge two functions such that the arguments are merged and the output is merged

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two functions as follows:

```
def eq_2(x):
    A, P, E, EA         = x
    return              np.array([E*A, EA, EA, E*P])

def eq_3(x):
    A, P, E, EA         = x
    return              np.array([E**2, E, E, E])
```

Subsequently I make a list and save it as '`v`':

```
v = [eq_2, eq_3]
[<function eq_2 at 0x7f2>, <function eq_3 at 0x7f3>]
```

Now my problem is: How can I treat `v` as a function that takes an **argument `x` of `shape=(8,)` and returns a result of `shape=(8,)` ?**

Furthermore, I want to be able to merge as many functions as I wish (i.e. increase the `v = [eq_2, eq_3]` term).

Comment: I suppose you missed actual function call `eq_2_15(i)`

Comment: No, I think the OP still wants an argument x.

Comment: *v* is a list. What do you mean by "treat it as a function"?

Comment: I think the OP wants a function that will iterate over v.

Comment: @quamrana No point in iterating over a list where all the elements are identical

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: @Stuart would it work to define the list v instead as a function?

Answer (score 0):

I the length of the input is always 8, I think you could split the input into two parts, feed it to the two functions, and concatenate the outputs.

```
import numpy as np

def eq_2(x):
    A, P, E, EA         = x
    return              np.array([E*A, EA, EA, E*P])

def eq_3(x):
    A, P, E, EA         = x
    return              np.array([E**2, E, E, E])


v = lambda x: np.hstack((eq_2(x[:4]), eq_3(x[4:])))

v_result = v([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```